# Import Module via AWS Lambda Console Editor

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying out an application in NodeJS. Have the following imports

```
var https = require('https'),
    aws4  = require('aws4')
```

However, get the error

`"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'aws4'",`

Code works when execute locally on desktop after installing aws4 using `npm install aws4`. How to install a module when editing lambda script in aws console lambda editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add modules from Lambda's console. You will have to use a package manager (like [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) or [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)) and install the dependencies you need. This means declaring them in `package.json` and running `npm/yarn install` before uploading your function to AWS Lambda. A `node_modules` folder will be generated with all the packaged dependencies inside it. Zip it and upload it.

Your `package.json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws4": "^1.8.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

If you want to make your deployment life easier, you may want to take a look into [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) and the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/).

Keep in mind that if your package is too large (and too large,for AWS's console is only <s>2MB</s> 3MB according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list)) after the dependencies are added you may lose the ability to edit the code inline through AWS's console, which means you'd have to use your own editor/IDE to edit the code before uploading it.